# Pinterest api - Get user detail

Tags: api, pinterest

I want to fetch user detail of pinterest's logged in user.
Currently, I am able to to login through api and I get access token also.

Now I want to get that user's detail.

I tried to search for it but not a luck.

**Note : I want to fetch that user's pin so I am using below api.
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/(USERNAME)/pins/?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN
For this I want (USERNAME).**

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Did you find the answer?  Stuck on the same step....

Answer (score 0):

https://api.pinterest.com/v2/me?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

returns the user data

{“username”: “Name”,
“image_url”: “http://d30opm7hsgivgh.cloudfront.net/avatars/image.jpg”,
“full_name”: “xyz abc”,
}

call this API and get users Details